# Handle with null JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jira

I am new to JSON and jQuery. What I am doing is get the JSON object from the api and display it as a table. But some elements in JSON array are null

For example; 
A JSON array looks like this :

```
[
  {"key":"first" , "name" :{"last":"Owen"} , "age" :{"number": 18} },
  {"key":"second" , "name" : null , "age" :{"number": 20}  } ,
  {"key":"third" , "name" : {"last":"Jay"} , "age" :null }
]
```

So to input to the table, I do this:

```
$.each(jsonarray, function(i,data){
 $("<tr>").append(
   $.('<td>').text(data.key),
   $.('<td>').text(data.name.last),
   $.('<td>').text(data.age.number)).appendTo('.table');
});
```

so the thing is they will get error:

> Cannot read property 'last' of null ; Cannot read property 'number' of null

because in the second and third element, name is null and age is null. Therefore,  there is no such thing is `name.last` and `age.number` to add in.

What I want is whenever they get something like that, they automatically return "No Information" to add into the table

However, I still don't know how to do it. I did try to write an function to check. For example like this :

```
    function check1(datum){
    if (datum !== null && datum !== undefined){
        return datum.last;
    }
    else {
        return "No Information"
    }
}
    function check2(datum){
    if (datum !== null && datum !== undefined){
        return datum.number;
    }
    else {
        return "No Information"
    }
}
```

But it is very tedious because I need to write 2 separate function to check (1 for name and 1 for age). I just wonder is there any elegant way to do one function for all?

Comment: Please summarize what is the exact issue. Do you want to traverse this JSON array or you are getting any null value?

Comment: I want whenever encountering null they will give me " No information" to add to the table instead of throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this meet your need?

```
var noDataTip = 'No Information';
$.each(jsonarray, function(i,data) {
    $("<tr>").append(
    $('<td>').text(data.key),
    $('<td>').text( (data.name && data.name.last) || noDataTip),
    $('<td>').text( (data.age && data.age.number)) || noDataTip).appendTo('.table');
});
```

Comment: sorry but can you help me explain the logic in this way , im quite confused how it can work

Comment: `(data.name && data.name.last)` means that only `data.name` exists, then the next `data.name.last` will run, and this statement will return the value of `data.name.last` if exists, otherwise will return the value of  `data.name`;

Comment: `(data.name && data.name.last) || noDataTip` means that will return the value of  `(data.name && data.name.last)` if exists, otherwise will return the value of noDataTip.

Answer (score 1):

try this. :)

```
$.each(jsonarray, function(i,data){
    if(data.key === undefined || data.key === null){
        data.key = 'none';
    }
    if(data.name === undefined || data.name === null){
        data.name = 'none';
    }
    if(data.age === undefined || data.age === null){
        data.age = 'none';
    }
    $("<tr>").append(
        $.('<td>').text(data.key),
        $.('<td>').text(data.name.last),
        $.('<td>').text(data.age.number)
    ).appendTo('.table');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.each(jsonarray, function(i,data){
        $("<tr>").append(
        $.('<td>').text(data.key),
        $.('<td>').text( data.name && data.name.last ? data.name.last : "No Information"),
        $.('<td>').text( data.age && data.age.number ?
 data.age.number : "No Information").appendTo('.table');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks man , this works too , is this a conditional operator ??

Comment: this is inline if, else function. makes it shorter, cleaner and easier to read

Comment: in this code you first  make sure data.name or data.age exists. if it does, then you check if the data.name.last or data.age.number exist and if they do then you return the statement after the '?'. otherwise you return the statement after ':'.  this is short form of inline if statement. you can use this in many languages. you can read more on that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/conditional-ternary-operator-decrement-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that makes a simple check for null:

```
function checkForNull(item) {
var data = "No information";
  if(!item === null) {
     data = item;
   }    
   return data;    
}
```

Then you could use it as follows:

```
$.('<td>').text(checkForNull(data.key))
```